# gcc: confused about -static -shared -fPIE -fPIC -Wl,-pie

Tags: gcc, compilation, static-linking

I'm trying to build clang, with all library static linked in. So that I can run it on CentOS 6 with ancient GCC 4.4 version.

At first, I think adding the option `-static` by turning on LLVM_BUILD_STATIC is enough. But in the link stage, it errors out.

> dynamic STT_GNU_IFUNC symbol `strcmp' with pointer equality in `/usr/lib/../lib64/libc.a(strcmp.o)' can not be used when making an executable; recompile with -fPIE and relink with -pie

So, I add `-fPIE -Wl,-pie` to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, and it says

```
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_ATOMICS_WITH_LIB
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_ATOMICS_WITH_LIB - Failed
CMake Error at cmake/modules/CheckAtomic.cmake:49 (message):
  Host compiler must support std::atomic!
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/config-ix.cmake:307 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:590 (include)
```

I checked the `cmake/modules/CheckAtomic.cmake` file, It compiles the following code

```
#include <atomic>
std::atomic<float> x(0.0f);
int main() { return (float)x; }
```

with command

> /home/hailin/gcc-4.8.3-boost-1.55/rtf/bin/g++  -fPIE -Wl,-pie -DHAVE_CXX_ATOMICS_WITHOUT_LIB -std=c++11  -static -lm
>
> /home/hailin/gcc-4.8.3-boost-1.55/rtf/bin/g++  -fPIE -Wl,-pie -DHAVE_CXX_ATOMICS_WITH_LIB -std=c++11  -static  -lm -latomic

The command with option `-Wl,-pie` reproduce the same error.

It seems like a dead end. Is there any conflict between `-shared` and `-fPIE -Wl,-pie` ?

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but in case someone else hits it: apparently you need to pass `-pie` to the compiler driver (gcc/g++), not just the linker (`-Wl,-pie`). Some startup object files differ for PIE (e.g. `Scrt1.o` instead of `crt1.o`) and these are passed by the driver to the linker, so the driver needs to know that you're making a PIE.