# Build llvm/clang with static libraries by default

Tags: cmake, llvm-clang

I need to use custom llvm/clang in machines that Ubuntu version varies.
I want build my llvm/clang with all shared libraries (libc, libm and etc.) replaced with static libraries to avoid runtime crash caused by out-of-date shared libraries. Is there a way to link static libraries by default?

I use CMake to build clang and wonder if there's something like `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` flag to control system libraries.

My problem is almost the same with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43930447/gcc-confused-about-static-shared-fpie-fpic-wl-pie?rq=1).

Comment: "And I want build my llvm/clang with all shared libraries(libc, libm and etc.) replaced with static libraries" - Do you have **static** version of these libraries (libc, libm)? As far as I know, `gcc` is "binded" with libc, so to build `libc` statically you need to rebuild `gcc` too.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes I have static version libraries(libc.a, libm.a), and now I'm trying to figure out what changes made to CMakelists.txt, or somthing else, can do static linking.